# Selecting multiple Trello cards in order to move them to another list

Tags: trello, trello-cards, trello-lists

How do I select multiple cards in Trello so that I can move them onto another list?

I would like to pick, say 10 cards, that are located adjacently to each other and drag and drop them to another list.

Comment: You might try hoverig on cards and using the . and , shortcuts

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for the same feature today while checking Trello out and I found that it's not possible for the moment.

You can vote for this request, like many of us did already:
https://trello.com/card/multi-select/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1367

Comment: Link is dead :(

Comment: Yeah, the link show empty page https://trello.com/c/undefined/107-multi-select

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct solution but a neat workaround: Move one card somewhere in the target list then hover and use the "R" (repeat action) shortcut. Not my answer - just wanted to pass it on! Found on this other answer: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/149365/16753

Answer (score -1):

They added the feature! Just click on the list options and select *Move all cards in this list ...*, then choose a list to move them too.
Huge win!

Comment: The set of cards to be moved probably doesn't coincide with the set of cards in some list.

Comment: Moving all cards is not the same as moving multiple cards.