# Move all filtered cards from a list to another

Tags: trello, trello-lists, trello-labels

Every list has a "Move all cards in this list" menu option. Once filtered by labels, this option remains the same, not affected by the filter. In other words, it will still move all cards, not just filtered ones. (Plus the list shows the total number of cards, it would be nice to see how many fit the filter, right?)

How to do that then? (Imagine like hundreds of cards. Keyboard shortcuts help, but still is pretty mechanical work.)

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do it (https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/43602/118250)

Alternating between the < or > key and the left or right arrow keys can be pretty quick to move from one list to the next, though hundreds would still take a while.
See: http://outside.hotjar.com/2014/07/04/8-trello-keyboard-shortcuts-you-must-learn-today-to-plan-and-collaborate-more-efficiently/

Answer (score 2):

Just as the name implies, the action moves all cards from the list without taking into account if you have a filter applied. The feature you are looking for is not available in Trello as of today.