# How to select multiple cards in a Trello board

Tags: trello, trello-cards

I need to select multiple cards (let's say after a filter operation) to add them in a checklist of another card. I do not see any way to perform this operation.
Another close use case I have is to perform multiple cards edits: like assigning the same member to multiple cards or adding the same label to multiple cards.

Comment: Trello support answered me that it's not supported: "we do not currently have a way in the UI to select multiple cards at a time and take action on them. I could see how that would be very valuable, though..."

Comment: We see this functionality as useful - for example to link root cards (features) to detailed cards (dev tasks and bug fixes) we use prefix in card names. May be voting for the question will motivate Trello team to prioritize this task

Answer (score 10):

Some of the tasks you mentioned can be performed with the keyboard. I.e. while you're not in add card mode, you can press "3" to add the third label to the card your mouse is over. So just hovering over all of the cards and pressing 3 over each one will add the appropriate label. So take a look at the keyboard shortcuts (which has its own keyboard shortcut "?"), to see if that works for you.

Comment: nice shortcut @McKay.

Comment: The keyboard shortcut to add a label is a nice fast way of adding labels but how is this an answer tot he question of how to select multiple cards? Shouldn't this have been a comment?

Comment: You make a good point, but what he's really asking is how to perform the same task repeatedly quickly? This is my workaround to answer that.

Comment: This is an excellent shortcut. It's faster to apply labels to a dozen cards this way than by a bulk method, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this a little bit faster by:

1. Doing what you want with one card (you can use all actions you can find in the hotkeys help section you get by pressing the key "**?**")
2. Hovering over another card and pressing the key "**R**".
3. Repeat for every other card you want the same thing to happen.

**R** is the key to repeat the last action done on another card for the actual card.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I've seen [this Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multiselect-for-trello/jlnfnpelianecpjoeahaeihmkhnkakof) that does exactly what you want.

Comment: Batch Actions for Trello works great!

Answer (score 0):

As of today, there is no way to do that on Trello, which is sad. You have to do that manually for every card you want to assign a label or a member.

Comment: Please read the [Help Center article on promotion](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).

Comment: Simply removing the link doesn't reduce the self-promotion aspect.  There's little "meat" to the answer left without the product recommendation.